# Output differing between `dependencies` and `androidDependencies`

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, gradlew

What are the differences between

`./gradlew :app:dependencies`

and

`./gradlew :app:androidDependencies`

?

All I've been able to notice is that `androidDependencies` includes `.jar` and `.aar` in the output graph. Why is this the case and is there a way to include these files in the dependency output via `dependencies`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `./gradlew :app:tasks` to see a short description of each Gradle task that is runnable in the `:app` project. The description that I see for each of the `androidDependencies` and `dependencies` Gradle tasks is as follows:

```bash
androidDependencies - Displays the Android dependencies of the project.
dependencies - Displays all dependencies declared in project ':app'.
```

Sadly, the descriptions here don't do a great job of differentiating between the two Gradle tasks. However, on running each of the two Gradle tasks, I see two differences in the output, as follows:

1. The `androidDependencies` task calls out whether the library is packaged as an `aar` or a `jar`. The `dependencies` task does not offer this information. (You have already called this difference out in your question.)
2. The `androidDependencies` task prints a flattened list of the project's dependencies. The `dependencies` task, on the other hand, prints a nested graph of the project's dependencies.

A further difference between the two tasks is that you can provide a `--configuration` option to the `dependencies` task to restrict its output to a single configuration. For example, if you run `./gradlew :app:dependencies --configuration debugCompileClasspath`, this will only display the dependencies for the `debugCompileClasspath` configuration. The `--configuration` option is not available for the `androidDependencies` task.

Comment: thanks Adil! I'll be sure to check the provided descriptions in the future